# Simple armature creation script results in a crash when attempting to set bone parenting

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, parent

My full script is more complex than this, but the issue I'm having can be reproduced with these 9 lines of Python code that create an armature with a single bone:

```
import bpy
rig = bpy.data.armatures.new("rig")
rigObj = bpy.data.objects.new("rig", rig)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(rigObj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = rigObj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bone = rig.edit_bones.new("bone")
bone.length = 1
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
```

This works almost as expected. However, after running the script, if you try to parent any object to the bone (manually, through the 3D viewport), Blender crashes. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or a step I'm leaving out here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In my case i parented a Cube to the bone after running your script and it runs fine. no crashes on the latest blender 3.4. what version are you using?

Comment: @Harry McKenzie I'm on 3.3, so I guess maybe this got fixed in 3.4. A little odd, considering that 3.3 is the LTS version. In any case, the solution I posted seems to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, setting the armature's active bone fixes this problem. Here's an update to the script above that works perfectly:

```
import bpy
rig = bpy.data.armatures.new("rig")
rigObj = bpy.data.objects.new("rig", rig)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(rigObj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = rigObj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bone = rig.edit_bones.new("bone")
bone.length = 1
bpy.data.armatures["rig"].edit_bones.active = bone
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
```